# how to efficiently select multiple slices from an array?

Tags: python, numpy, indexing

Given an array

```
d = np.random.randn(100)
```

and an index array

```
i = np.random.random_integers(low=3, high=d.size - 5, size=20)
```

how can I efficiently create a 2d array `r` with

```
r.shape = (20, 8)
```

such that for all `j=0..19`,

```
r[j] = d[i[j]-3:i[j]+5]
```

In my case, the arrays are quite large (~200000 instead of 100 and 20), so something quick would be useful.

Comment: Does `low` and `high` make any difference? Like `low=0, high=d.size - 8` and `d[i[j]:i[j]+8]`?

Comment: yes, it does make a difference. if an element of `i` is `<3`, then `i[j]-3` is negative. similar for the upper bound.

Comment: But if `all(0<=elem<=92 for elem in i) is True` then `d[i[j]:i[j]+8]` would be the same, right?

Answer (score 1):

You can create a windowed view of your data, i.e. a `(93, 8)` array, where item `[i, j]` is item `[i+j]` of your original array, as:

```
>>> from numpy.lib.stride_tricks import as_strided
>>> wd = as_strided(d, shape=(len(d)-8+1, 8), strides=d.strides*2)
```

You can now extract your desired slices as:

```
>>> r = wd[i-3]
```

Note that `wd` is simply a view of your original data, so it takes no extra memory. The moment you extract `r` with arbitrary indices, the data is copied. So depending on how you want to use your `r` array, you may want to delay that as much as possible, or maybe even avoid it altogether: you can always access what would be row `r[j]` as `wd[j-3]` without triggering a copy.

Comment: Don't use take here, unless you first rewrite the function. Its great to know that take is faster often, but it is at least generally a very bad idea (and certainly not faster) here.

Comment: @seberg I am guessing it is the copying, that has to happen no matter what, that makes it a bad idea, right? Will edit my answer: thanks!

Comment: Well, the normal slicing won't do the temporary copy I believe... So if you take only a few items, you could be bloating memory up big time...